# Input alias from external source in angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

I am working on a directive and I ran into a problem. I tried to define inputs with aliases like that:

alias.enum.ts:

```
export enum Alias {
    myAlias = 'myAlias'
}
```

mydirective.directive.ts

```
import {Alias} from './alias.enum.ts';

@Input(Alias.myAlias) myAliasedInput: number;
```

Turned out it is not working. But with string literal as input alias there is no problem:

mydirective.directive.ts

```
@Input('myAlias') myAliasedInput: number;
```

Why is it working like that?

Comment: Try [this syntax](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kprq1b?file=src%2Fapp%2Falias.directive.ts)

Comment: Thank you. It is working, but kinda strange for me giving its own type signature instead of a specific (number etc.) type.

Comment: [You can use it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pfqzyg?file=src/app/alias.directive.ts), simply use the correct type (a string isn't a number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comments, here is the correct syntax :

```
@Input(Aliases.myAlias) alias: string;
@Input(Aliases.myAlias) alias: Aliases.myAlias;
```

Either type it with the enum, or with the correct type.

Comment: It works of the shelf. I think I made a mistake somewhere else. Thank you.